# login using ajax and return mutiple lots of data from php login script?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have the following simplified version of my php / MySQL login script which I use to login my user:

```
<?php
session_start();  
include("config.php");


$tbl_name="internal_users";  
$tbl_name2="supplier_users";  

$username=$_POST['username1']; // Fetching Values from URL
$password=$_POST['password1'];

$username = stripslashes($username);  // Secure Values
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_name = '$username' UNION
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 where user_name = '$username'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


$hashed_pass = crypt($password, $Blowfish_Pre . $row['salt'] . $Blowfish_End);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {


if($hashed_pass === $row['user_password_hash']) {
$array['login_success'] = true;
} else {
if($hashed_pass !== $row['user_password_hash']) {   
$array['login_success'] = false;
  } 
}

echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

Next I use the following ajax code to run the above script in real time without the need of a page refresh:

Jquery/Ajax code:

```
       <script>
function submitForm() {
var myusername = $("#myusername").val();
var mypassword = $("#mypassword").val();
var array = $.parseJSON(data);




$("#myusername").keypress(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $("#myusername").css("border", "1px solid #fff");
    }
});

$("#mypassword").keypress(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $("#mypassword").css("border", "1px solid #fff");
    }
});

if (myusername == null || myusername == "" || mypassword == null || mypassword == "") {
if (myusername == null || myusername == "") { document.forms["form"]["myusername"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
if (mypassword == null || mypassword == "") { document.forms["form"]["mypassword"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
$( ".home_column" ).effect( "shake" ); 
} else {
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("include/validate_login.php", {
username1: myusername,
password1: mypassword
}, function(data) {
var array = $.parseJSON(data);
if (data['login_success'] == false){
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)', 
            content:'<h21>Incorrect Login Details</h21>'
})  }else{
var array = $.parseJSON(data);
 if (data['login_success'] == true){
  $(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)', 
        content: '<h21>Hello '',</h21><div class="user_image"><img src="data/user/image/'+data.substring(13)+'/default.jpg" alt="user" style="width:90px;height:90px;"></div><div class="spinner"><div class="rect1"></div><div class="rect2"></div><div class="rect3"></div><div class="rect4"></div><div class="rect5"></div></div><h21>Preparing your Dashboard</h21>'    
}) 
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   window.location = 'dashboard.php'; 
  }, 4500);

  } }
$('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
});
}
}

$(document).ready(function() {   
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('keypress click', '#submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitForm();
});
});
</script>
```

I am trying to fetch my array ['login_sucess'] to see if it is true or false and can't understand why the code is not working, my jquery/ajax won't execute at all. Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why not just add it to a session variable? $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_first_name'] and $_SESSION['user_id] = $row['user_id'] ?

Comment: @balslev I could do but I am not sure then how I would echo a session variabe  in my ajax

Comment: I would indeed use json also then. In your ajax call use dataType: 'json', and in your php file, echo out json_encode($output); Then in your success, you can console.log(data), and take it from there?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `json_encode` to convert an array containing your data into a json string:

```
$array = array(
  'first_name' => $row['user_first_name'],
  'user_id' => $row['user_id']
)

if($hashed_pass === $row['user_password_hash']) {
  $array['login_success'] = true;
} else {
  if($hashed_pass !== $row['user_password_hash']) {   
    $array['login_success'] = false;
  } 
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

You would then need to convert this back into an array within your jQuery:

```
var array = $.parseJSON(data)
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, could you show me an example please of how this might look php server side and also how I would then retrieve it in my ajax? thanks

Comment: ok and how would I then be able to choose which piece of data I echo out in my jquery/ajax?

Comment: @Markharris `array['first_name']` would get your first name

Comment: Instead of echoing the values you just build an array. After your last else in your login-script you then echo the json-encoded array.

Comment: @Markharris I have edited my code using your scenario.

Comment: @TommyJinks thanks, I am sruggling to get my ajax to work now though, I am checking the array login_sucess is true or false like so: "if (array['login_success'] = true){" is this right?

Comment: @Markharris When comparing variables within an `if` statement, make sure to use `==` instead of `=`. `==` is used for comparision, `=` is used for assignment.

Comment: @TommyJinks I still cannot get this to work, the jquery just doesn't seem to execute at all no, I have updated my question to show you the new code

Comment: `var array = $.parseJSON(data);` needs to go within your AJAX request (just before your `if` statements concerning `login_success`). The `if` statements are incorrect, if you look at my example in the comments, I used square brackets, not parentheses: `data['login_success']` not `data('login_success')`. You have also spelt success wrong.

Comment: @TommyJinks I have updated my question again with your corrections, however I am still not able to get my jquery/ajax to work

Comment: As you have named your parsed json `array`, this needs to be changed in the if statements. Instead of `data['login_success']`, it should be `array['login_success']`. I only used `data` as a name as it is usually used on SO as a reference to what is returned by an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing three different variables combine it to a single array and encode with json  like given below,

```
$info[] = array(
                 'message' => $item->field_uname_value,
                 'userid' => $row['user_id'],
                 'username' => $row['user_first_name']
             );
 echo json_encode($info);
```

To process json value using jquery please check the below code ,

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonvariable);
obj[message];
```

Answer (score 0):

As above said by Tommy Jinks you can use json_encode or  You can do like this

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

if($hashed_pass === $row['user_password_hash']) {   // Check Password is   valid

 echo "login_success||".$row['user_id']."||".$row['user_first_name'];
}else{
   if($hashed_pass !== $row['user_password_hash']) {   

  echo "login_fail||".$row['user_id'];
} }

}else{
echo "login_wrong";     
}
```

And Split your response by "||" using javascript
    after success

```
  data = data.split("||");
    data[0] - first data
    data[1] - your user id 
    data[2]  - user_first_name
    data = data[0];
also check for undefined value as well
```